# auto populate field on NewForm.aspx with value from a field on another List 2007

Tags: jquery-ui

I am trying to achieve a 1-to-many type system.  I have 2 lists. [LIST_A] is the main list and has a column named SIMSID.

[LIST_B] is the many secondary list that I want to relate to [LIST_A] by the SIMSID.

Ultimately I want to be able to view [LIST_A] in standard view.  When I click to edit an item in the list, I want to open the NewForm.aspx from [LIST_B] and populate [LIST_B].[column1] with [LIST_A].SIMSID.

Is this possible?  I've been searching and haven't found anything.  Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2007? Some ideas here: http://surpoint.blogspot.com.ar/2009/12/relaciones-maestro-detalle-en.html

It is a lees heavy option with javascript. However I think best option of master detail are built with c#.